# How to add the System Date to a function that requires the date in a string format?

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the RGoogleAnalytics package to automate reports on our website. Queries look like this:

```
# Create a list of Query Parameters
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2014-11-28",
                   end.date = "2014-12-04",
                   dimensions = "ga:pageTitle",
                   metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:pageviews",
                   max.results = 1000,
                   table.id = "ga:XXXXXX")
```

I want to replace those dates with the Sys.Date()-1 and Sys.Date(), respectively, but the function requires that they are in string format. I've thought about writing a separate function that prints out the query.list with the Sys.Dates as a string, but I'm not certain how to go about that.

Comment: @agstudy you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
as.character(Sys.Date()-1)
```